# Group data with same value in two columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, datatable

I have some data in a SQL server table with different To and CC recipients listed in two columns.

Is it possible to get different data sets with all rows that have the same values in To and CC columns?

Would it be easier to split the datatable in my C# code?

EDIT:

Suppose I have data like this :

```
  A       B       C       To            CC
-----   -----   -----    -----         -----
  132    45     test     em1@cc        ec7@cc
  133    34     new      em4@cc        ec3@cc
  134    65     here     em3@cc        ec5@cc
  135    78     one      em7@cc        ec4@cc
  136    45     check    em1@cc        ec5@cc
  137    85     two      em6@cc        ec1@cc
  138    56     email    em1@cc        ec5@cc
  139    65     var      em3@cc        ec5@cc
```

I would like to get the data separated as below (Rows where To value is same, and CC value is same):

```
  A       B       C       To            CC
-----   -----   -----    -----         -----
  132    45     test     em1@cc        ec7@cc


  A       B       C       To            CC
-----   -----   -----    -----         -----
  133    34     new      em4@cc        ec3@cc

  A       B       C       To            CC
-----   -----   -----    -----         -----
  134    65     here     em3@cc        ec5@cc
  139    65     var      em3@cc        ec5@cc

  A       B       C       To            CC
-----   -----   -----    -----         -----
  135    78     one      em7@cc        ec4@cc

  A       B       C       To            CC
-----   -----   -----    -----         -----
  136    45     check    em1@cc        ec5@cc
  138    56     email    em1@cc        ec5@cc


  A       B       C       To            CC
-----   -----   -----    -----         -----
  137    85     two      em6@cc        ec1@cc
```

Comment: Can you please provide us with some sample data and expected outcome. I am having a hard time to understand your question

Comment: Please add sample data, you desired output and what you have tried to your question so that we may best assist you in fixing it.

Comment: If you are using a data adapter to put results in to a DataTable in c# it is each to split using linq : dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Column Name")).ToList();  The type string can be replace with the type of the column.  You can do same with two columns : dt.AsEnumerable().GroupB y(x =>new object[] { x.Field<string>("Column Name 1"),  x.Field<string>("Column Name 2")}).ToList()   You can get new datatableby replaing .ToList() with .Select(x => x.CopyToDataTable()).ToList();

Comment: select * from mytable t where t.[to] = t.cc

Comment: IMO, retrieving data where to = cc is sql server's job. How you present the data is c#'s job.

Comment: @SOS, I am modifying my code to try out the grouping in Datatable; so can it be done for multiple columns?